# Boosting Search Result According to specific Value in ElasticSearch with Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, magento-1.9

I want to integrate boosting in elastic search with aggregation of result.
my json query for displaying search result with grouping using aggregation is given below.

```
{
  "min_score": 0.5,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "search_result": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store_name.untouched",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "search_result_second": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "store_name.untouched": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            },
            "size": 3,
            "from": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "all_stores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store_name.untouched",
        "size": 0
      }
    },
    "all_categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_name.untouched",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "all_category_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_category_ids"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "all_brands": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand.untouched",
        "size": 0
      }
    },
    "all_colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 0
      }
    },
    "min_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "actual_price"
      }
    },
    "max_price": {
      "max": {
        "field": "actual_price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By using above query i get 10 buckets of each store with the grouping of 3 products of each store in it .The sample output for the above query is given below.

```
buckets: [10]
0:  {
key: "ABC"{
    0:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

1:  {
key: "EFG"{
    0:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

2:  {
key: "HIJ"{
    0:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .
    }
}


.
.
.

unitill bucket 10 stores.
```

Now i want to apply Boost to specific store that it must always come first in search result and then  the remaining store will come later on. When i query to elastic search.
So if i want to boost **storename = EFG** then the resultant json should be.

```
buckets: [10]

0:  {
key: "EFG"{
    0:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:EFG
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

1:  {
key: "ABC"{
    0:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:ABC
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

2:  {
key: "HIJ"{
    0:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .

    }
    1:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .
    }
    2:{
        storename:HIJ
        .
        .
        .
    }
}


.
.
.

unitill bucket 10 stores.
```

Is there any solution to achieve this result using elasticsearch.

Comment: I really doubt if it's possible without using scripts inside of ES...

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas thanks for your comment, but i tried to use script in ES but mostly the scripts examples that i find for ES are based on number type of value so can you please elaborate that how to boost store name using script

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that helpful. I've never really used scripts in ES. I just knew that it's impossible to do it with ES functionality...

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas ohhh ! so is there any way to change the order of buckets  keys.